# #VALUE! errors after setting displayed outline level from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have reduced my problem to the following test case:

1. create a new workbook;
2. enter a constant value, e.g. `123` into `Sheet1!A1`;
3. define a name, e.g. `foo`, that refers to the formula `=CHOOSE(!$A$1, Sheet1!$A$1)`;
4. enter the constant value `1` into `Sheet2!A1`;
5. enter the formula `=foo` into some other cell on `Sheet2`, e.g. `Sheet2!B1`: observe that, as expected, the result is the value that was entered into `Sheet1!A1` in step 2 above;
6. create then run a VBA procedure containing the following code:

   ```
   Sheets("Sheet1").Outline.ShowLevels 1
   ```

You will notice that the cell from step 5 now contains a `#VALUE!` error.

Moreover, a simple sheet recalculation (whether using the <kbd>F9</kbd> key or the `Application.Calculate` method) does not resolve the problem: one must instead perform either a *full* recalculation from VBA (using the `Application.CalculateFull` method) or else a *full rebuild* from the interactive UI (using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> key combination).

Through trial-and-error, I have ascertained that for this condition to arise:

- the `CHOOSE()` index argument must involve a relative-sheet cell reference (not constants or absolute-sheet references);
- the `CHOOSE()` value argument that is being indexed must involve a reference to another sheet;
- the change of displayed outline level must arise from within a VBA *procedure* (not from the outline controls in the interactive UI or the VBA Immediate Window); and
- the `ShowLevels` method call (whose arguments are irrelevant) must be applied to a sheet that is referenced amongst any of the value (though not index) arguments to `CHOOSE()`.

What's going on?

I would very much like to collapse a worksheet that I am referencing amongst the value arguments to `CHOOSE()` to its highest outline level without triggering this error, as a full recalculation of my actual workbook (still only a few seconds) is undesirable from a UX standpoint.

Suggestions for a workaround (whilst still using a defined name containing the `CHOOSE()` function together with a relative-sheet index argument) would be most welcome!

My platform: Excel 2010 (14.0.6123.5001, 32-bit) on Windows 7 Home Premium (SP1, 64-bit).

Comment: For what it's worth, I am unable to reproduce the issue in Excel 2002 SP3 (10.6871.6870, 32-bit) on Windows 7 Home Premium (SP1, 64-bit).

Comment: @mwolfe02, hmm.... I can reproduce on Excel 2010 (14.0.6123.5001, 32 Bit) on XP, SP3

Comment: @SeanCheshire: Good to know.  It sounds like a bug that was introduced by MS (likely when going from Excel 2003 to 2007).  Which simply begs eggyal's question: is there a workaround?  ...  And this is the point where I bow out and hope others can assist.

Comment: I can reproduce on Excel 2003 SP3 (11.8346.8341, 32-bit) on Windows 7 Professional (SP1, 64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your named formula: `=CHOOSE(!$A$1, Sheet1!$A$1)`, specifically the `!A1`

The leading `!` is invalid (without a preceeding sheet name, eg `Sheet1!$A$1` *is* valid).  Just specify a sheet and your problem goes away.

I suspect this may not satisfy you, depending on *why* you used `!A1` in the first place.  If it's that you want `=foo` to use an index value from `A1` *on the sheet the formula `=foo` is placed on* use `INDIRECT("A1")` instead of `!A1`

---

BTW I think your may have found a bug, or at least undefned behaviour, in that the formula `=CHOOSE(!$A$1, Sheet1!$A$1)` is invalid and should *always* return a `#Value` error.

Comment: I've been using leading `!` (without sheet name) within named formulae for years, and had always understood that it was a valid *relative sheet reference* (i.e. resolves to the referencing sheet, as you describe); however, I can't cite any documentation in support of this so perhaps it is unreliable. That said, I'm pretty certain that I discovered it through (an older version of) Excel adding a leading `!` to an otherwise unqualified reference (i.e. with no sheet named) - but I can't reproduce that behaviour now.

Comment: I was using this approach in order to avoid using volatile `INDIRECT` calls in the first place, so whilst your suggestion provides a workaround as asked it sadly is no good for me!

Comment: I havn't come across using `!` for relative sheet references before.  Doing a little investigating, I find you can't record a macro while setting a `Name` to use it, nor can you write `VBA` to set a names' `.RefersTo` to use it.  This suggests to me it's unsupported behaviour.  As to solutions, if `Indirect` is no good, I guess you must be using a lot of them.  I suspect any change to the formula will either be volatile or break the calculation tree (and so require a forced recalc, so thats no good either).

Comment: One very ugly option might be to keep track of where the `Names` are used, and force calculate only those cells in your `VBA`

Answer (score 0):

if you include this UDF, does it give the correct behaviour?

```
Public Function fooUDF(inCell As Range)
    fooUDF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(inCell.Value).Range("A1").Value
End Function
```

It may have performance implications using a UDF instead of a defined name/formula.
It may also be problematic that it takes an in parameter, which your original approach does not. This can be circumvented by running a macro to introduce a worksheet defined formula per sheet like this: (the part looping over all necessary sheets is not included)

```
Public Sub InsertName()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Names.Add Name:="fooformula", _
        RefersToR1C1:="=fooudf(Sheet2!R1C1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Agreed, deleting out the text before the and including the ! (bang) sign doesn't work. When the formula is viewed again a sheet name and a bang sign is showing.